# Dotnet restore works fine locally, but hangs on build server. Times out on packages from private NuGet repository

Tags: nuget, tfsbuild

We execute a `dotnet restore` command on a build server, via the TFS build agent tool. All of our packages restored from NuGet feeds just fine, until today. Today we had added some NuGet packages that point at packages in a private Proget, NuGet repository. It started throwing the error in the TFS logs:

```
Retrying 'FindPackagesByIdAsyncCore' for source 'http://proget/[our-domain]/nuget/NUGET/FindPackagesById()?id='packagename''.
```

Then it times out. I have checked my NuGet.Config file to make sure the proxy setting works. This works without any issue for packages outside the proxy. Here is the setting for that:

```
<configuration>
    <config>
        <add key="http_proxy" value="http://ourproxy:port" />
    </config>
```

Why is this not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out what was going on, and it was actually Docker that helped me find the issue. Docker requires that, when using a private registry behind a proxy, you exclude domains for the private registry. Similarly, NuGet requires that setting as well for private feeds.

Here is the config setting now:

```
<configuration>
    <config>
        <add key="http_proxy" value="http://ourproxy:port" />
        <add key="no_proxy" value="domainOfPrivateNuGetFeed" />
    </config>
```

Once I added that "no_proxy" setting, everything worked just fine!

Comment: Thanks for the reminder. Had to wait until the restriction expired.